# Tabularx - Automaticallay shrink row length to longest row

Tags: tabularx, textwidth

I need to shrink the row length of a table to fit the longest row. Here is what I have done

```
\begin{table*}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Component} & \textbf{Description}\\
        \midrule
        Clients & Users of the application which might be applications on their own\\
        Load Distributor & Distributes incoming requests to application instances\\
        Application & Runs business logic defined by developer\\
        Metric Engine & Monitors and collects metric from application and provides it to other components\\
        Infrastructure API & Provides API to adjust (add/remove) resources\\
        Auto-Scaler & Runs the auto-scaling algorithm based on metric collected by Metric Engine\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \centering
    \caption{Auto-Scaler component summary}
    \label{tab:auto-scaler-sum}
\end{table*}
```

This produces something like this with long unused padding at the end of all columns.
[image: Table]
Currently I resize it manually like `0.9\textwidth`. I tried with different commands like `\linewidth` or `\columnwidth`, but it doesn't seem to function as I expect. Is there any automatic way of telling `tabularx` to shrink the row length to fit the longest row?

Comment: Why are you using a `tabularx` at all there? `\begin{tabular}{ll}` should be fine.

Comment: Other than that, the  `ltablex` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`, has this behaviour, unless you stipulate the `\keepXColumns` directive, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for some reason you need the `X` specifier in your table, the `ltablex` package combines the functionalities of `longtable` and `tabularx`.

From the documentation:

> Another feature that has been added is to treat the X columns like ‘ l ’ columns if the table contents would allow that to happen without exceeding the specified width of the table. In other words, the specified width is treated as the maximum allowed and not the exact width of the table. This feature is the default but can be disabled (or enabled) with \keepXColumns (or \convertXColumns).